# How to play / stop MediaPlayer using checkbox in preferences?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-mediaplayer, preference

In this code, i made a preference check box with key "music" in xml folder.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference 
    android:title="Music"
    android:key="music"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:summary="Check/Uncheck this to switch on/off sound"
    />

    </PreferenceScreen>
```

If this checkbox is checked , then my mediaplayer will start playing . If this is unchecked , it will not start. But the music is not stopping immediately after unchecking it.

What i want to implement is, if i uncheck the checkbox in preferences the music should stop immediatly

Below is the code i wrote in my MainActivity , i also used this code in onPause() method. But nothing works.

Hope you help me guys.. Thanks in advance..

```
        MediaPlayer song;
        song= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bg);
        song.setLooping(true);
        SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        Boolean music=prefs.getBoolean("music", true);
        if(music == true)
        song.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

The music stop and start should be on checking/unchecking the checkbox.

```
yourCheckbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        //is yourCheckbox checked?
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            if(song.isPlaying())
                song.stop();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The check box is located in a Settings page ( Preferance ) not in my Activity page. So i can't use this method.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a PreferenceActivity you can do this,

```
music = findPreference("music");

music.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        //code to stop Music
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: where should i specity this..? In mainactivity or preference class ..??